# Declare a variable with a class

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I try around with storing data in a model. For that I created a class, which looks like that:

```
export class Data {
  constructor(moons: number, color: string) {
    this.moons = moons;
    this.color = color;
  }

  moons: number;
  color: string;
}
```

I import the class with `import { Data } from './data.model';` in my Service.
With the next step I declare a var `earth` with the type `any`, that will work.

```
export class DataService {
  private earth: any;

  constructor() {
    this.earth = new Data(1, 'blue');
  }
}
```

But I want to set this variable to the class type Data. But it doesn't work when I set `private earth: <Data>;`

I got the following error:

```
10:24 - error TS1005: '(' expected.
```

Whats the right way to do get the class as type?

Comment: just for making it strongly typed, no need to create a class and instantiate, instead create an interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
private earth: Data;
```

The statement `private earth: <Data>` isn't valid typescript syntax.

---

Furthermore, if you intended to use generics then you can use `Data<any>`. It signifies that the class accepts a *generic* type and would mean that it should be defined as below in order for  `private earth: Data<any>` to work.

```
export class Data<T> {

 ...

}
```